# How much AP does it cost to launch the catapult with the calibrated catapult built?

Tags: die2nite

I know the normal catapult uses 4AP to launch an object into the desert, but I can't find the AP cost for the calibrated catapult anywhere. Is it 3AP? 2AP? I'd rather not build it and find out.

None of my towns are every planning on building the catapult, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

the wiki says it reduces catapult's AP need from 4 AP to 2 AP.

http://die2nitewiki.com/wiki/Calibrated_Catapult